# How to hide content of previous and next siblings in a certain wrapper but not of clicked div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I wrote a function for this purpose but it is not achieving my targets. Currently it is hiding either all previous or all next individually. But when i apply both at a time they hide even that div's content. Kindly help in this regard.

Html Part is

```
<div id="improveformob" class="improve-wrapper">
    <div id="integrity" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>I</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Integrity</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inclusiveness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>I</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Inclusiveness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We work as a team and want others to succeed. We care about our customers, employees, work environment and social responsibilities.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>
                                    <img src="images/new_slices/improve-m.png" width="80" />
                                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="passion" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>P</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Passion</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="responsivness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>R</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Responsiveness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="openness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>O</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Openness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="valcreation" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>V</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Value Creation</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="excellence" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>E</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Excellence</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = id.id;
    $('#' + e).next().removeClass();
    //$('#' + e).not(this).siblings().addClass("hide");
    $('#' + e).prevAll().addClass('hide');
    $('#' + e).nextAll().addClass('hide');
}
```

Kindly help in this regard that where i am lacking the logic.

Comment: can OP share html or demo?

Comment: Put the `not` after the call to `siblings`.

Comment: What is this trying to achieve: `$('#' + e).next().removeClass();`  ?

Comment: Here i am trying to remove that clicked div's content div. Which is next to it.

Comment: @4castle its not working by doing that.

Comment: I think  '$('#' + e).removeClass("hide").siblings().addClass("hide");' would be fine enough to do the work. Please check this one and reply.

Comment: @guradio HTML Shared. Help will be much appreciated to achieve this.

Comment: @Sharukhkshaji its not working bro :(

Comment: Did you debug the code and sure that the 'var e' is the actual 'id' of the div?

Comment: What is the expected result? can u explain?

Comment: @BillingSystems i dont get what you want but can you check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6rn4udcs/) if this is what you want

Comment: @Sharukhkshaji yes i did.

Comment: @sabith what i want is when i click on integrity it just shows its content placed right after its div having its on tagline. Now when i click on any other word like responsiveness then it hides all open details of any other.

Comment: @guradio basically i wanted to make all details to be hidden at first. when someone clicks on integrity just show its details and when someone clicks on openness then hide all other details.

Comment: @guradio i have updated the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/6rn4udcs/ This is what i achieved. Now here if you see i just unhide the clicked div content. I want that the div i click just show its content. No other div's content to be shown.

Comment: @BillingSystems updated the fiddle [check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6rn4udcs/2/)

Comment: @guradio sir its just opening the respective div's content. Not hiding the other opened div's content.

Comment: @BillingSystems check the updated demo i just read your last comment so wasnt clear at first but the updated demo does what you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6rn4udcs/2/)

Comment: @guradio Thanks alot :) thats what i want :). Appreciated :)

Comment: @BillingSystems i will post it as answer so we can close the OP ok?

Comment: @guradio Yeah sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  console.log(id)
    var e = id.id;
    $('.box').next().addClass('hide');//add the class hide to all so al will be hidden
    $(id).next().removeClass('hide');//then remove the hide class from the target div to show it
    //$('#' + e).not(this).siblings().addClass("hide");
}
```

```css
.red{color:red}
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="improveformob" class="improve-wrapper">
    <div id="integrity" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>I</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Integrity</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inclusiveness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>I</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Inclusiveness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We work as a team and want others to succeed. We care about our customers, employees, work environment and social responsibilities.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>
                                    <img src="images/new_slices/improve-m.png" width="80" />
                                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="passion" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>P</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Passion</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="responsivness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>R</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Responsiveness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="openness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>O</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Openness</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="valcreation" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>V</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Value Creation</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="excellence" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <span>E</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Excellence</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. Add display none to all information div
2. Add hide class to all information div on click
3. Remove the class hide from the target div to show the target div

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

I hope this is what you are looking for:

HTML

```
<div id="improveformob" class="improve-wrapper">
                <div id="integrity" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>I</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Integrity</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="inclusiveness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box ">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>I</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Inclusiveness</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We work as a team and want others to succeed. We care about our customers, employees, work environment and social responsibilities.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>
                            <img src="images/new_slices/improve-m.png" width="80" />
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="passion" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>P</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Passion</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="responsivness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>R</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Responsiveness</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="openness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>O</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Openness</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="valcreation" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>V</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Value Creation</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="excellence" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <span>E</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hide info">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Excellence</h1>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = id.id;
  $('.info').addClass("hide");
  $("#"+e).next().removeClass("hide");

 }
```

CSS

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This works for you. It displays only the clicked section and hides all other.

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="improveformob" class="improve-wrapper">
                    <div id="integrity" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>I</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Integrity</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="inclusiveness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>I</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Inclusiveness</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We work as a team and want others to succeed. We care about our customers, employees, work environment and social responsibilities.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>
                                <img src="images/new_slices/improve-m.png" width="80" />
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="passion" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>P</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Passion</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="responsivness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>R</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Responsiveness</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="openness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>O</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Openness</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="valcreation" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>V</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Value Creation</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="excellence" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span>E</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Excellence</h1>
                        <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

<script>
  
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = id.id;  
 $('#improveformob').find('.hide').hide(); // hide all when clicked
 $('#' + e).next('.hide').show(); // show the next one on click
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="improveformob" class="improve-wrapper">
        <div id="integrity" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>I</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Integrity</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="inclusiveness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>I</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Inclusiveness</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We work as a team and want others to succeed. We care about our customers, employees, work environment and social responsibilities.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="passion" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>P</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Passion</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="responsivness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>R</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Responsiveness</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="openness" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>O</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Openness</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="valcreation" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>V</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Value Creation</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="excellence" onclick="toggle_visibility(this);" class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <span>E</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #1D99D8;">Excellence</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">We act with integrity and internal code of honor by always doing the right thing. We honor our commitments and never sacrifice our standards.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function toggle_visibility(btn) {
            var e = $(btn).attr("id");
            $(".box").each(function () {
                $(this).next("div").addClass("hide");
            })
            $(btn).next("div").removeClass("hide");
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```